# Angular with Firestore storage getting image from bucket

Tags: angular, firebase, image, google-cloud-firestore, storage

I have some images saved in my storage in a bucket. I am trying to load these images in my template, based on agencyId. Right now, I'm getting the image, but only if I put the path. How can get my agencyId - which is the name of my image into my component, then add the image etx, or how would I change my code in myu component, and then how do I get it in my template.

my component

```
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {AngularFirestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {Agency} from './Agency.interface';
import {AngularFireStorage, AngularFireStorageReference, AngularFireUploadTask} from '@angular/fire/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-agencies',
  templateUrl: './agencies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./agencies.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

})
export class AgenciesComponent implements OnInit {
  ref: AngularFireStorageReference;
  logoUrl: any;
  bcUrl: any;
  filePath: string;


  agencies$ = this.afs.collection<Agency[] | any>('agencies').valueChanges().pipe(tap(console.log));

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore, private afStorage: AngularFireStorage) {
    const storage = this.afStorage.storage.app.storage(
   'gs://agency-logos-paid-keeper');
    this.logoUrl = storage.ref().child(`/thumbnails/12345678910_700x100.png`)
      .getDownloadURL();


  }
```

my template

```
<div class="clr-row" *ngIf="agencies$ | async as agencies">
  <div class="clr-col-lg-4 clr-col-12">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let agency of agencies">
      <div class="card-header">
        <div><b>{{agency.name}}</b></div>
        <div>{{agency.phone |slice:0:3 }}-{{ agency.phone
          | slice:3:6 }}-{{ agency.phone | slice:6:10 }}</div>

      </div>
      <div class="card-block">
        <div class="card-media-block">
          <div class="card-media-description">
            <img [src]="logoUrl | async" class="card-media-image" alt="AFS" id="logoImg"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-text">

<!--          <div class="card-media-block">-->
<!--            <div class="card-media-description">-->
              <img src="/assets/card.png">
          Time Sheet:
          <span *ngIf="agency.pocTimesheetRequired == true"><cds-icon shape="success-standard"
                                                                      solid></cds-icon></span>
          <span *ngIf="agency.pocTimesheetRequired == false"><cds-icon shape="times" solid></cds-icon></span>
<!--            </div>-->
<!--          </div>-->
          <!--            {{agency.pocTimesheetRequired}}-->
<!--          (click)="uploadImage($event, agency.agencyId)"-->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                routerLink="/agencies/edit-agencies/{{agency.agencyId}}"
        >Edit Agency
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warn"

        >Add Agency
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution lies not in getting the image from the storage bucket, rather storing the url of the saved file in your storage bucket into Firestore.

```
const ref = this.storage.ref('/path/to/file.ext')  // Filepath 

// 'file' comes from the Blob or File API
ref.put(file).then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(
    url => {
      // Save the url alongwith agency data in the same collection 
    }
  )
});
```

Now, you will always have the url of the file alongwith the other data. This is also useful when you later want to delete or update the files from the storage.

Comment: thanks for the helpful information @T. Sunil Rao . Two questions: when you say that the file comes from the Blob or File Api can you be more specific? question two: I don't know what my child path should be. is it the name of the collection? if I pass the bucket path, like so, gs://agency-logos-paid-keeper/thumbnails.png I get an error Firebase Storage: ref() expected a child path but got a URL, use refFromURL instead.

Comment: Filepath is the path you would like to see inside your storage bucket. e.g. '/uploads/agency/id/thumbnail.png'

Comment: The file is the file you want to upload. It uses File API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File Can use it like let file= new File([""], "foo.bar"). Also refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files